# How to verify the Literal text on the UI

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

Here is part of the UI where i have got some literal texts like

```
Opportunity Name    Momentum Test (ID=AANA-19KVBE)
Account             Account Internal
Owner               Christopher Braden
Sales Order Region  North America
Locale English      United States
Currency            US Dollar
```

The piece of code for the above is as follows

```
<table class="datatable" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="oddrow">
        <td>Opportunity Name</td>
        <td class="wrap_content">
            Momentum Test (ID=AANA-19KVBE)
            <br>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com">View in Salesforce</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="evenrow">
        <td>Account</td>
        <td class="wrap_content">
            Akamai Internal
            <br>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com">View in Salesforce</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="oddrow">
        <td>Owner</td>
        <td>Christopher Braden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="evenrow">
        <td>Sales Order Region</td>
        <td>North America</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="oddrow">
        <td>Locale</td>
        <td>English - United States</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="evenrow">
        <td>Currency</td>
        <td>US Dollar</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to retrieve these values individually, store it to compare it in a different page.

for example : i need to know "United States" is stored under "Location"

Please help me

Thanks & Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read and store all this information in a Map -

```
Map<String,String> map = new Map<String,String>;

List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='datatable']/tbody/tr")); 

for(int i=1;i<=list.size();i++){

  String key = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='datatable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]")).getText();
  String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='datatable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[2]")).getText(); 

   map.put(key,value);
 }
```

In this way you can read all the information in the table and store it in Map to be used later. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thanks for the quick response friend. Will try it out and let you know :)

Comment: the code is inside the class "datatable". `driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr"));` returns all the elements under `<tr>` in every part of the UI. What should i modify if I wanna extract only the elements in that class. The xpath of the element "Opportunity Name" is `.//*[@id='maininside']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`.

Comment: Hi Hari : No luck ... `List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='datatable']/tbody/tr")); ` is returning null :(

Comment: i used the whole xpath specified in my earlier comment and m able to achieve what i intended it :) .. Thanks for the response :)